# Flutter error on building files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have newly installed Flutter on Android Studio. I had a source code of flutter which I want to open using it. I installed the latest flutter plugin and flutter SDK. But when I try to run the app, it shows me the following error:

```
Compiler message:
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:92:3: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
  PictureStream();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter extends Diagnosticable {
               ^

Compiler message:
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:92:3: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
  PictureStream();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter extends Diagnosticable {
               ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Flutter SDK\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Flutter SDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am completely new to this and have no idea where this error is pointing. I have the latest Flutter SDK version: Flutter 1.17.0 and Dart 2.8.1, it's a stable version. My Android Studio version is 3.6.2

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing this in your terminal :

`flutter pub cache repair`

If it doesn't work, deleting the flutter folder, along with the cache folder should do the job.

Comment: terminal error : 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @dhruvbhati: that error can be searched for - it is a very common one on Windows.

Comment: hey , i runned the code in terminal , but getting this error : Reinstalled 181 packages.
Failed to reinstall 2 packages:
- image 2.1.12
- video_player 0.10.6
pub finished with exit code 69

Comment: is there any way i can reinstall these two only , which didnt installed properly . and if it dosent work then can you tell me the location of the flutter folder and the cache folder to delete

Comment: succesfully done the cache repair , but the error not solved . Please help me as fast as possible . thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case i solved this problem adding the latest version of flutter svg to pubspec.yaml

Check the link to install latest version: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#-installing-tab-