# Intellij Dart Webdev Cannot Find "devtools0.9.7+1/build"

Tags: dart, web, intellij-idea, devtools

I had no issues at all building my project, I duplicated it to start a new one, still worked then I made some code changes then I randomly can't build it at all. Even the previous project stopped building and I have no idea what the error is. I've tried purging the dart pub cache and everything but it seems this specific error hasn't happened to anyone yet from what I've searched.

Output:

```
Unhandled exception:
Invalid argument(s): A directory corresponding to fileSystemPath "/Users/chrisl/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/devtools-0.9.7+1/build" could not be found
#0      createStaticHandler (package:shelf_static/src/static_handler.dart:50:5)
#1      defaultHandler (package:devtools_server/src/external_handlers.dart:40:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      serveDevTools (package:devtools_server/src/server.dart:183:21)
#3      DevTools.start (package:dwds/src/servers/devtools.dart:26:15)
#4      Dwds.start (package:dwds/dwds.dart:132:33)
#5      WebDevServer.start (package:webdev/src/serve/webdev_server.dart:130:25)
#6      ServerManager.start (package:webdev/src/serve/server_manager.dart:23:38)
#7      _startServerManager (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:103:27)
#8      DevWorkflow.start (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:196:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      DaemonCommand.run (package:webdev/src/command/daemon_command.dart:108:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
#11     _CommandRunner.runCommand (package:webdev/src/webdev_command_runner.dart:38:24)
#12     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#13     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:223:31)
#14     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
```

[Build Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0kR0.png)

Comment: please check the solutions at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52318 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663167/flutter-error-on-building-files-in-android-studio